# Configure a project with FTXUI on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vcpkg

First, I installed the [FTXUI](https://github.com/ArthurSonzogni/FTXUI) using the [VCPKG](https://vcpkgx.com/details.html?package=ftxui):

```
vcpkg.exe install ftxui
```

Then, I created a new project on Visual Studio Community 2022 to try to execute the [button example](https://arthursonzogni.github.io/FTXUI/examples_2component_2button_8cpp-example.html) (just copied and pasted) from the FXUI documentation.

So, I modified the project properties in VS 2022 to add directories where the VCPKG placed the headers and libraries of FXTUI:

[Include Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ReJl.png)
[Library Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yrI2.png)

But, when I try to build the project, a get this errors:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YnWI.png)

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 14 unresolved externals test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\test_tui\x64\Debug\test_tui.exe   1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl ftxui::to_string(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (?to_string@ftxui@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@3@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl ftxui::ConstStringRef::ConstStringRef(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >)" (??0ConstStringRef@ftxui@@QEAA@V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z)  test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\test_tui\test_tui\test_tui.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > __cdecl ftxui::to_wstring(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?to_wstring@ftxui@@YA?AV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@3@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl ftxui::ConstStringRef::ConstStringRef(char const *)" (??0ConstStringRef@ftxui@@QEAA@PEBD@Z) test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\test_tui\test_tui\test_tui.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::Node> __cdecl ftxui::operator|(class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::Node>,class std::function<class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::Node> __cdecl(class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::Node>)>)" (??Uftxui@@YA?AV?$shared_ptr@VNode@ftxui@@@std@@V12@V?$function@$$A6A?AV?$shared_ptr@VNode@ftxui@@@std@@V12@@Z@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl `int __cdecl main(int,char const * * const)'::`2'::<lambda_3>::operator()(void)const " (??R<lambda_3>@?1??main@@YAHHQEAPEBD@Z@QEBA@XZ)    test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\test_tui\test_tui\test_tui.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::Node> __cdecl ftxui::text(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?text@ftxui@@YA?AV?$shared_ptr@VNode@ftxui@@@std@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@3@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl `int __cdecl main(int,char const * * const)'::`2'::<lambda_3>::operator()(void)const " (??R<lambda_3>@?1??main@@YAHHQEAPEBD@Z@QEBA@XZ) test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\test_tui\test_tui\test_tui.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::Node> __cdecl ftxui::separator(void)" (?separator@ftxui@@YA?AV?$shared_ptr@VNode@ftxui@@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl `int __cdecl main(int,char const * * const)'::`2'::<lambda_3>::operator()(void)const " (??R<lambda_3>@?1??main@@YAHHQEAPEBD@Z@QEBA@XZ) test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\test_tui\test_tui\test_tui.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::Node> __cdecl ftxui::gauge(float)" (?gauge@ftxui@@YA?AV?$shared_ptr@VNode@ftxui@@@std@@M@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl `int __cdecl main(int,char const * * const)'::`2'::<lambda_3>::operator()(void)const " (??R<lambda_3>@?1??main@@YAHHQEAPEBD@Z@QEBA@XZ)   test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\test_tui\test_tui\test_tui.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::Node> __cdecl ftxui::border(class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::Node>)" (?border@ftxui@@YA?AV?$shared_ptr@VNode@ftxui@@@std@@V23@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl `int __cdecl main(int,char const * * const)'::`2'::<lambda_3>::operator()(void)const " (??R<lambda_3>@?1??main@@YAHHQEAPEBD@Z@QEBA@XZ)   test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\test_tui\test_tui\test_tui.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::Node> __cdecl ftxui::vbox(class std::vector<class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::Node>,class std::allocator<class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::Node> > >)" (?vbox@ftxui@@YA?AV?$shared_ptr@VNode@ftxui@@@std@@V?$vector@V?$shared_ptr@VNode@ftxui@@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$shared_ptr@VNode@ftxui@@@std@@@2@@3@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl `int __cdecl main(int,char const * * const)'::`2'::<lambda_3>::operator()(void)const " (??R<lambda_3>@?1??main@@YAHHQEAPEBD@Z@QEBA@XZ)    test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\test_tui\test_tui\test_tui.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: static struct ftxui::ButtonOption __cdecl ftxui::ButtonOption::Simple(void)" (?Simple@ButtonOption@ftxui@@SA?AU12@XZ) referenced in function main   test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\test_tui\test_tui\test_tui.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::ComponentBase> __cdecl ftxui::Container::Horizontal(class std::vector<class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::ComponentBase>,class std::allocator<class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::ComponentBase> > >)" (?Horizontal@Container@ftxui@@YA?AV?$shared_ptr@VComponentBase@ftxui@@@std@@V?$vector@V?$shared_ptr@VComponentBase@ftxui@@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$shared_ptr@VComponentBase@ftxui@@@std@@@2@@4@@Z) referenced in function main    test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\test_tui\test_tui\test_tui.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::ComponentBase> __cdecl ftxui::Button(class ftxui::ConstStringRef,class std::function<void __cdecl(void)>,class ftxui::Ref<struct ftxui::ButtonOption>)" (?Button@ftxui@@YA?AV?$shared_ptr@VComponentBase@ftxui@@@std@@VConstStringRef@1@V?$function@$$A6AXXZ@3@V?$Ref@UButtonOption@ftxui@@@1@@Z) referenced in function main    test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\test_tui\test_tui\test_tui.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::ComponentBase> __cdecl ftxui::Renderer(class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::ComponentBase>,class std::function<class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::Node> __cdecl(void)>)" (?Renderer@ftxui@@YA?AV?$shared_ptr@VComponentBase@ftxui@@@std@@V23@V?$function@$$A6A?AV?$shared_ptr@VNode@ftxui@@@std@@XZ@3@@Z) referenced in function main  test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\test_tui\test_tui\test_tui.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: static class ftxui::ScreenInteractive __cdecl ftxui::ScreenInteractive::FitComponent(void)" (?FitComponent@ScreenInteractive@ftxui@@SA?AV12@XZ) referenced in function main test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\test_tui\test_tui\test_tui.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl ftxui::ScreenInteractive::Loop(class std::shared_ptr<class ftxui::ComponentBase>)" (?Loop@ScreenInteractive@ftxui@@QEAAXV?$shared_ptr@VComponentBase@ftxui@@@std@@@Z) referenced in function main  test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\test_tui\test_tui\test_tui.obj    1   
Warning LNK4272 library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\vcpkg\packages\ftxui_x86-windows\debug\lib\ftxui-component.lib    1   
Warning LNK4272 library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\vcpkg\packages\ftxui_x86-windows\debug\lib\ftxui-dom.lib  1   
Warning LNK4272 library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' test_tui    C:\Users\lyang.medeiros\workspace\vcpkg\packages\ftxui_x86-windows\debug\lib\ftxui-screen.lib   1
```

How to set this project properly?

How to configure a project with FTXUI on Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: Looks like you did not link to the libraries. Setting link directories is only one part of the linking process. You need to specify what libraries to link to in the `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies` setting. When you are doing that be careful as the Release configuration and Debug should have different libraries because Release and Debug in msvc have incompatibilities due to extra information stored in Debug structures.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the path of libraries to use the debug version and added the libraries' names on `Aditional Dependencies: ftxui-component.lib; ftxui-dom.lib; ftxui-screen.lib`. But I continue to have the same errors.

Comment: Are any of the errors "can not open XXXX.lib" where XXXX is one of the libs you just listed?

Comment: no @drescherjm.

Comment: Please paste the errors themselves into the question, rather than posting an image of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the library folder name describes, you should use x86(Win32) and debug\lib in the  Library Directories.